# How do I get updated/extended functions with OpenGL in Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl, wgl

The specific OpenGL function I am trying to call in my case is:  glTexImage2DMultisamplehttps://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2DMultisample.xhtml

I have followed this tutorial: https://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/opengl-in-a-proper-windows-app-no-glut/

I understand making a Window, getting a handle, drawing in that window, etc. I have not had issues in the past with these function calls with GLEW/GLFW/GLUT etc. But I would like to remove these crutches.

The functions from the tutorial that are OpenGL specific are seen from the Windows 10 dev kit. The kit is far newer than the implementation of the wanted function and should be present, I think.

Comment: A GL extension loader (like GLEW) isn't a "crutch". It is absolutely neccessary to use the extension mechanism to get to anythihg past GL 1.1 on windows, since only OpenGL 1.1 is part of the windows API (and, consequently, `opengl32.dll`).

Comment: Using GLEW makes it WAY easier than having to load the function pointers manually. Use the most recent GLEW build and it should have the most recent GL extensions. You may wish to compile it manually to explicitly specify which extensions you would like support for.